# Relative compactness of exponents of measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

I'm trying to understand a result in Linde's *Probability in Banach Spaces: Stable and Infinitely Divisible Distributions* related to the relative compactness of a sequence of finite Radon measures with respect to the topology of weak convergence of measures.

I thought about what's written in the red rectangle a lot, but I can't figure out how the claims follow from the propositions. I've provided the relevant definitions and propositions below. It would be great if someone could point out how we obtain the claims in more detail.

[image]

---

### **Defitions/Propositions**

[image]
[image]
[image]